# Quartz.net - invoke remote job

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have installed quartz.net as windows service and configured it with a job and trigger in quartz_jobs.xml. This requires the job dll to be present locally under quartz server. If my job is on a remote server, how do we specify that in the quartz_jobs.xml? Do I still need to copy the dll to quartz server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll with the job must be present on the Quartz.Net server and it must be accessible by the server as well. Usually you want to copy it to the same folder where the quartz dll is.